# На декстопе не работает IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, vue.js, observer

Проблема в том, что IntersectionObserver API не работает в декстопной версии на Vue. Как только включаешь режим Mobile, всё грузится. При чем проблема появилась недавно, раньше это работало. Уже поставил полифилл, но не помогло.

С чем это может быть связано?

```
export default {
    inserted: el => {
        function loadImage(){
            if(el.childNodes.length !== 0){
            el.childNodes[0].srcset = el.childNodes[0].dataset.srcset;
            el.childNodes[2].src = el.childNodes[2].dataset.src;

            }else{
                el.src = el.dataset.src
            }
        }

        function callback(entries, observer){
                entries.forEach(entry =>{
                if(entry.isIntersecting){
                    loadImage();
                    observer.unobserve(el);
                }
            })
        }

        function createIntersectionObserver(){
            const options = {
                root: null,
                threshold: [0]
            }

            const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

            observer.observe(el);
        }

        if(!window['IntersectionObserver']){
            loadImage();
        }else{

            createIntersectionObserver();
        }

    }
}
```

**template**

```html
<picture v-lazyload>
  <source type="image/webp" :data-srcset="imagesWebp" style="max-width:100%; height:auto">
  <img :data-src="images" style="max-width:100%; height:auto">
</picture>
```

Вот в мобильном режиме, когда элемент (el) заходит в зону видимости `viewport`, он выводит этот элемент в консоль, например, а в декстопной версии - он как будто не видит элемент, ничего не происходит ...

Comment: Добавил сам код

Comment: в начале функции loadImage, да lazyload для изображений

Comment: Нет, изображения вообще не открываются, тобишь функция вообще не срабаывает, соотвестенно артибуты не заменяются....а в мобильном режиме, все работает как надо....Причем изначально, когда я писал этот код - всё работало

Comment: Это директива, зачем тут template - это не шаблон

Comment: ааа пардон, обновил код

Comment: Только какая разница какой тепмлейт, если он в моб то работает

Comment: Ну как не срабатывает, если все работает. Элемент при прокручивании появляется в консоли, если вывести. Тут дело видимо во viewport. Почему каша? он берет первый и третий дочерний узел

Comment: три, там еще есть узел text - в консоли выводит. Тут не в этом проблема, даже если просто убрать функционал показа изображений, он элемент не обнаруживает, еще до того, как менять атрибуты

Comment: Могу в демонстрации показать, если интересно...

Comment: Так а я о чем говорю на МОБ это показывает. а в декстопе нет. тут проблема не в самих изображениях, а в методе IntersectionObserver. Он элемент не видит, чтобы в нем что то менять... могу по скайпу демонстр провести